# event.srcElement.sourceIndex and document.all[ ] in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a legacy system works on Firefox too. It just works on IE, so I'm here to ask you how can event.srcElement.sourceIndex works on FF?
I know event.srcElement in FF is event.target, but in target I don't have sourceIndex property. I also need to replace window.document.all[ ] for something that works on FF.
The actual code are below:

```
var index = event.srcElement.sourceIndex;
window.document.getElementById('txtElementId').value = window.document.all[index - 1].id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I recently had a similar issue, where I found a solution so I thought I would post it here for good measure.

```js
var index = Array.from(document.all).indexOf(event.srcElement);
window.document.getElementById('txtElementId').value = document.all[index - 1].id;
```

The performance of document.all in combination with indexOf can be quite slow, but in my case, I did not notice any severe performance issues. This is something you should be aware of though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your elements have ids you could do something like this using jQuery

```
$('#id').index('*')
```

If they dont, you can temporary add a class/id and remove when you are done

```
$(event.srcElement).attr('id','myId');
console.log($('#myId').index('*'));
$('#myId').attr('id','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont rely on features that exists only on specific browsers. That is why it's good to use jQuery and it's target with whatever attributes it does give you. And if it exists only in firefox try to find another attribute to use which exists across all browsers rather than rely FF implementations.

Comment: I think you don't understand. Today my legacy app works just on IE and I want it working on IE and FF, as cross browser app.
I can use Jquery too, but I don't know how to use it or pure js to fix my issue.

Comment: Yes and it will not. http://help.dottoro.com/ljbxdemp.php you can see that sourceIndex property is supported ONLY in IE and Opera. So you need to find a way not to use this property.

Comment: Thats why I'm asking here.